# convert all ts files in a folder to mp4 with same name

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, mp4

I have a folder with several video files, some .mkv some .ts some .mp4, all different names.

I want to convert all ts files into mp4 files with the same name.

what do I type in the command line to use ffmpeg to do this?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I've only found ways to do it one by one, I need a mass way for all the .ts files to be recognized and converted into .mp4 files with the same name and quality

Comment: Better add your command for one file to the post.

Comment: There are a number of file conversion utilities that do what you request, such as https://file-converter.org/, and https://www.windows7download.com/win7-vsdc-free-video-converter/wqdxffwi.html . Why use ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in *.mkv *.ts; do ffmpeg -i $i $i.mp4; done
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I use [File Converter](https://file-converter.org/) which uses the context menu in Explorer. I like it because it is easy and light, and can convert an entire folder.

It also works for other file types than just videos.

And while it can be configured quite a lot, it doesn't seem to work on .ts files that I've found.

So for .ts files, I use a PowerShell script (.ps1) file, which I found [here](https://www.junian.net/tech/powershell-ffmpeg-batch/), to batch convert a folder with the following command:

```
$originalVids = Get-ChildItem *.ts -Recurse

foreach ($inputVid in $originalVids) {
    $outputVid = [io.path]::ChangeExtension($inputVid.FullName, '.mp4')
    ffmpeg.exe -i $inputVid.FullName -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a aac -map_metadata 0 $outputVid
}
```

Place the .ps1 file in the folder you want to convert, then double-click on it.

I like it because we can change the `*.ts` and `'.mp4'` to any other video format allowing us to essentially convert anything to anything (from what I've found so far).

Though, this method does make my PC run hard while it is converting. Yet, I will add that the quality of the conversion is quite good.